# Why does the icon not appear every time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap and fontawesome, and I am having problems with showing icons. Sometimes icons are showing ok, and sometimes it is not showing.

You can see the pictures

http://s11.postimg.org/p0o996rgf/error1.png this is ok

http://s27.postimg.org/42b91yyrj/error.png this is problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kupisajt.com/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.kupisajt.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.kupisajt.com/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.kupisajt.com/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://www.kupisajt.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

this is code which is creating icons in font awesome

```
<div class="feature-wrap">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

There is no pattern, it just sometimes shows, and then not. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: those are images hosted on some server - I don't see the correlation to bootstrap or fontawesome

Comment: I have created screen shots with problem and without it, I was trying not to post website address

Comment: The images are showing the icons not appearing, @ScottSelby

Comment: I have experimented, and I can see that when I use local fontawesome.min.css file, icons are not showing all the time, and when I use css file located on font awsome server it is working. How can I fix it to work from local server. I am using latest files and I have uploaded them to root directory.